# API to get app service plan consumption details

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-monitoring

I am searching for azure API which will give me the consumption details such as CPU Usage,Memory Usage, Data In-Out details for an App Service Plan. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

These metrics are made available by the [Azure Monitor Metrics API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list)

Here is an example for retrieving CPU and Memory percentage.

```
https://management.azure.com//subscriptions/xxxxxxx-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/CXPCommunityHub/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/xxxxxxxAppServicePlan/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01&metricnames=CpuPercentage%2CMemoryPercentage
```

You can specify a comma separated list of the metrics you wish to retrieve.